# Angular 5 - Conditional validators not working

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular5

If email field is not empty, then re-email field must be 'required',
For this I need to add conditional base validators in re-email field,
I have tried below code,

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">         
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label class="control-label">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" (blur)="reEnterEmail()" [ngClass]="{ 'quote-has-error' : startPageForm.controls['email'].invalid && startPageForm.controls['email'].touched}"
        formControlName="email">
        <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="startPageForm.controls['email'].hasError('pattern') && startPageForm.controls['email'].touched">Email is invalid</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label class="control-label">Re-enter Email Address :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" (blur)= "checkReEmail()" [ngClass]="{ 'quote-has-error' : startPageForm.controls['reEmail'].invalid && startPageForm.controls['reEmail'].touched}"
        formControlName="reEmail" id="reEmailId">
        <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="startPageForm.controls['reEmail'].touched && message == 'false' &&
        this.startPageForm.controls.email.value != this.startPageForm.controls.reEmail.value" >Email is invalid</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
this.startPageForm = new FormGroup({

              firstName : new FormControl( '', [Validators.required]),
              middleName : new FormControl( '', [] ),
              lastName : new FormControl( '', [Validators.required] ),
              suffix : new FormControl( '', [] ),
              dateOfBirth : new FormControl( this.dateOfBirth, [Validators.required, DateValidator, AgeValidator] ),
              gender : new FormControl( this.genderEnumConstants[0].value, [] ),
              maritalStatus : new FormControl( this.maritalStatusEnumConstants[0].value, [] ),
              aprtUntNumber : new FormControl( '', [] ),
              address : new FormControl( '', [] ),
              city : new FormControl( '', [Validators.required] ),
              stateId : new FormControl( '', [Validators.required] ),
              zipcode : new FormControl( '', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)] ),
              isMilitrayAddress : new FormControl( false, [] ),
              mobileNo : new FormControl( '', [Validators.required] ),
              homeNo : new FormControl( '', [] ),
              email : new FormControl( '', [ Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")] ),
              reEmail : new FormControl( '', [] ),
              notificationMethod : new FormControl( this.notificationMethodEnumConstants[0].value, [] ),
              policyTerm : new FormControl( this.policyTermEnumConstants[0].value, [] ),
              effectiveDate : new FormControl( effectiveDate, [DateValidator, MinDateValidator] ),

        });


    reEnterEmail() {

        this.startPageForm.controls['reEmail'].setValidators(this.setRequired());
    }

    setRequired() {

        if(this.startPageForm.controls.email.value != null  && this.startPageForm.controls.email.value != '') {
            return [Validators.required];
        } else {
            return [];
        }   
    }
```

On `email` field `(blur)="reEnterEmail()"` event I am setting validators to `reEmail` field. But I got following **error**.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Validators is not defined(…)
```

Comment: did you import Validators from '@angular/forms' ?

Comment: yes i have imported the Validators from '@angular/forms'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got key solution.
Actually the problem was I was not executing method `updateValueAndValidity();` after setting Validators to control.

**Component:**

```
reEnterEmail() {
        let reEmailControl = this.startPageForm.get('reEmail');
        if(this.startPageForm.controls.email.value != null  && this.startPageForm.controls.email.value != '') {
            reEmailControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
        } else {
            reEmailControl.setValidators([]);
        }
        this.startPageForm.get('reEmail').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```